# Jqgrid callback function not returning response

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I want to return data from my webmethod with Jqgrid Editurl.
I am returning object but I am getting 'null' data when I check with firebug and I am using 'aftercomplete' function for my need.
Can anyone help how to return data with editurl of jqgrid.

this is my service method

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static object ChangeLDetails(object data)
        {
            try
            {                
                BAL.BAL obj = new BAL.BAL();
                obj.BALChangeLDetails(data);
                List<Response> on = new List<Response>();
                on.Add(new Response() { Result = "success" });
                object ob = (object)on;
                return ob;                
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }
```

and Jqgrid add functionality

```
        {
            afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
                alert(postdata);
            },
            checkOnSubmit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                var postdata = { 'data': postData };
                return JSON.stringify(postdata);
            }
        },
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: please update in your question.

Comment: Actually I am inserting record and in DB it will check whether any duplicates or not. If duplicates exist then I am returning 'failed' message if not 'success' with the help of output parameter and that I am returning from webmethod to jqgrid add function.

Comment: You can use `afterSubmit: function (jqXHR,postdata, frmoper) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); return [true];}` for example to see the response from the server.